# unit testing for unverified user trying to login

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I've been trying to test for a user that hasn't been verified.

```
class TestLoginApi(TestCase):
    URL = '/rest-auth/login/'
    EMAIL = 'testuser@test
    PASSWORD = 'password'
    DATA = {'email': EMAIL, 'password': PASSWORD}

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(username='testuser', email=cls.EMAIL,
                                                    password=cls.PASSWORD)

def test_login_api_without_verification(self):
    response = self.client.post(self.URL, self.DATA, format='json')
```

The "response" line throws the following error

**Error**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
>       yield
>
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 601, in run
>       testMethod()
>
> File "/Users/docdocengineering3/GitHub/website/project/authorization/Tests/test_login.py", line 34, in test_login_api_without_verification
>       response = self.client.post(self.URL, self.DATA, format='json')
>
> File "/Users/docdocengineering3/.virtualenvs/docdoc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 548, in post
>       secure=secure, **extra)
>
> File "/Users/docdocengineering3/.virtualenvs/docdoc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 350, in post
>       secure=secure, **extra)
>
> File "/Users/docdocengineering3/.virtualenvs/docdoc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 416, in generic
>       return self.request(**r)
>
> File "/Users/docdocengineering3/.virtualenvs/docdoc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 501, in request
>       six.reraise(*exc_info)
>
> File "/Users/docdocengineering3/.virtualenvs/docdoc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 686, in reraise
>       raise value
>
> File "/Users/docdocengineering3/.virtualenvs/docdoc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
>       response = get_response(request)
>
> File "/Users/docdocengineering3/.virtualenvs/docdoc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
>       response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "/Users/docdocengineering3/.virtualenvs/docdoc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
>       response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "/Users/docdocengineering3/.virtualenvs/docdoc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
>       return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/Users/docdocengineering3/.virtualenvs/docdoc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
>       return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/Users/docdocengineering3/.virtualenvs/docdoc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
>       return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/Users/docdocengineering3/.virtualenvs/docdoc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py", line 76, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
>       return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/Users/docdocengineering3/.virtualenvs/docdoc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
>       return func.**get**(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
>
> File "/Users/docdocengineering3/.virtualenvs/docdoc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_auth/views.py", line 49, in dispatch
>       return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/Users/docdocengineering3/.virtualenvs/docdoc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 489, in dispatch
>       response = self.handle_exception(exc)
>
> File "/Users/docdocengineering3/.virtualenvs/docdoc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 449, in handle_exception
>       self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
>
> File "/Users/docdocengineering3/.virtualenvs/docdoc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 486, in dispatch
>       response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/Users/docdocengineering3/.virtualenvs/docdoc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_auth/views.py", line 92, in post
>       self.serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
>
> File "/Users/docdocengineering3/.virtualenvs/docdoc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 237, in is_valid
>       self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)
>
> File "/Users/docdocengineering3/.virtualenvs/docdoc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 435, in run_validation
>       value = self.validate(value)
>
> File "/Users/docdocengineering3/.virtualenvs/docdoc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_auth/serializers.py", line 105, in validate
>       email_address = user.emailaddress_set.get(email=user.email)
>
> File "/Users/docdocengineering3/.virtualenvs/docdoc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
>       return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/Users/docdocengineering3/.virtualenvs/docdoc/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 380, in get
>       self.model._meta.object_name
>
> Exception: EmailAddress matching query does not exist.

I have no idea why this is happening. It isn't a setup problem as I've tried actually running the system, creating a user (not verifying) and when I "PostMan" the same link, I get the correct error back

```
{"non_field_errors": [ "E-mail is not verified." ] }
```

So it works in the actual product but not when testing. Anyone know why? Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is the only test that I can't get to work, all the rest runs correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have your setting `EMAIL_VERIFICATION` set to `mandatory`.

So you either change it to `none` in tests or manually create `EmailAddress` object (it's required by django-allauth when mandatory verification is on)